# File name pattern matching in unix

Tags: unix, ksh

In a directory, I have different file names. 
I'm facing issue in matching the pattern. 
I have files with prefix 'abc' as below: 
abc123.10122013.txt
abc254.10122013.txt
abc542.54212013.txt
 and files with prefix ''abcdef' as below:
abcdef321.10212013.txt
abcdef321.12222013.txt
abcdef321.08252013.txt

In my Korn shell script, i'm doing some operation in for loop based on the prefixes. 
So whats happening is files with prefix 'abcdef' are included when doing for prefix  'abc'
As i am using wildcard like 'abc*'

```
while read base 
do
for file in $(ls "${base}"* | sort | head -4 )
do 
compress $file
done
done <xyz
```

So im planning to match 'abc' as abc with immediate 3 digit number 
and abcdef as with after abc alphabates.
Can any one suggest some good approach to crack this

Answer (score 0):

Try using `grep`:

```
PATT="abc[0-9]\{3\}"
for file in $(ls "${base}"* | sort | grep ${PATT} | head -n) do ... done
```

And for the abcdef files (assuming this is the only other pattern you're expecting):

```
PATT="abc[0-9]\{3\}"
for file in $(ls "${base}"* | sort | grep -v ${PATT} | head -n) do ... done
```

The first for-loop will pick up files starting with abc followed by 3 numbers. The second one will pick up those that don't follow this pattern, presumably abcdef.